# call display() instead of glutPostRedisplay() in reshape?

Tags: glut, freeglut

In `reshape()` function, can I simply call the callback function `display()` instead of `glutPostRedisplay()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could*, but it wouldn't be a good idea. Just let the message handler do its job.

If you need more control over message handling and rendering, you should use GLFW.